# Spark com.databricks.spark.csv is not able to load a snappy compressed file using node-snappy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snappy, databricks, apache-spark-2.0

I have some csv files on S3 that are compressed using the snappy compression algorithm (using `node-snappy` package). I like to process those files in spark using `com.databricks.spark.csv` but I am consistently getting an invalid file input error.

code:

```
file_df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true', codec='snappy', mode='FAILFAST').load('s3://sample.csv.snappy')
```

error message:

> 16/09/24 21:57:25 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip-10-0-32-5.ec2.internal): java.lang.InternalError: Could not decompress data. Input is invalid.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompressBytesDirect(Native Method)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:239)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BlockDecompressorStream.decompress(BlockDecompressorStream.java:88)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
>       at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.skipUtfByteOrderMark(LineRecordReader.java:208)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:255)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:209)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>       at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1305)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1305)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1897)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: If you are using spark 2.0 try this method csv of the class like this: `df = spark.read.csv('csv.file')`

Comment: spark.read.csv uses `com.databricks.spark.csv` and the same issue still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same problem that is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29871643/3009) - basically python snappy isn't compatible with Hadoop snappy.